# Pandas groupby mean unstacked data and then ploting them as horizontal stacked barchart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset like this

```
Category    Date    Score_1     Score_2     Level   
A       1/1/2020    130         145     Excellent
A       1/5/2020    145         148     Excellent
C       1/2/2020    107         109     Need-Improvement
B       1/1/2020    125         128     Good
C       1/7/2020    105         107     Need-Improvement
B       1/2/2020    127         117     Good
A       1/12/2020   117         126     Good
C       1/12/2020   123         124     Good
```

Dataset -2

```
Category    Mean    Excellent(%)  Good(%)   Need-Improvement(%)
A          130.6    66.67         33.33     0
B          126      0             100       0
C          111.6    0             66.67     33.33
```

I want to create a dataset-2 from dataset1 by creating mean from score_1 values and creating level values as columns and finding as percentage values for each category and level.
For this I wrote

```
Df_90=pd.DataFrame()
Df_90["Mean"]=df.groupby('Category')["Score_1"].mean()
Df_90=D_90.reset_index()
```

This achieved only the first one and not unstack. so tried below

```
df.groupby('Category')["Score_1"].mean().unstack('Level').head()
```

This threw error
KeyError: 'Requested level (Level) does not match index name (Category)'

Then plot the graph as horizontal bar chart for each category and stacked by the level values in percentage. The mean determines the length of the bar while the stacked becomes the level percentages within it.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate the mean and the level frequency separately and then combine them:

```py
mean_score = df.groupby('Category').agg(Mean=('Score_1', 'mean'))
level_freq = (
    df.groupby(['Category'])
        ['Level'].value_counts(normalize=True)
        .mul(100)
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .add_suffix('(%)')
)

result = pd.concat([mean_score, level_freq], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks but not able to plot using result=result.reset_index()       result.plot.barh(x="Category", y='Mean', stacked=True,
             title='Scores') Not sure  how to make it stack using the level_freq

Comment: Stacking `Mean` doesn't make sense as it's not a performance category. You should only stack the Need-Improvement / Good / Excellent columns: `result.drop(columns='Mean').plot.barh(stacked=True)`

Comment: Yes you are right I want the level_freq(Need-Improvement / Good / Excellent) to be stacked but I want the mean to indicate the length of the bars. The percentages are indicated in the stacks